# Planning to move to Italy

Tags: eu-citizens, residency, italy, business

I’m citizen of another EU country, but I have a big motor disability. I’m a software engineer and I assume that it won’t be possible from the beginning to work for an Italian company because my disability is not recognized there. I was thinking to start my own business, self employed, etc. The thing is that I don’t know if I can open my own business, if I’m not resident there.

I've read somewhere that I can get the residency if I have at least ~6000eur in my bank account and a private insurance. Even if my health status is stable and allows me to work full time, the private health insurance company will reject me.

Do you have any idea for me?

Comment: Yes, stay away from Italy. High taxation, deadly slow beaurocracy, social tensions. Maybe you have a very good reason to go to Italy, but my suggestions for my Italian friend is to leave as soon as possible. Move to Italy for a foreigners is just crazy (if he/she is not really rich)

Comment: @mucio thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it, but I have to move in Italy anyway. Please put your comment as an answer in order to vote it or mark it as solution. It seems that you are one of the few ppl from this forum with expertise in Italian rules.

Comment: actually Italian companies must hire people with disability (based on  the number of employees) but you have two problems: first is the language, if you don't speak Italian companies will not hire you, the second is the poor (or better absent) situation for people with a motor disability in Italy.

Comment: @GuidoPreite TY for your comment. Can you tell me which is ratio or the minimum number of employees for which a company has to hire disabled people?

Comment: from 15  to 35 employees at least 1 person with disability, from 36 to 50 at least 2, from 50 a percentage, but I have not exact data on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As and EU citizen, you can stay in Italy (or in any other UE states) up to 3 months without any formality.

For stay more than 3 months, you will need one of these reason:

- a work (employed or self-employed)
- attending a recognized school
- sufficient resources (about 6000 euro for Italy if you are alone) and a private health insurance
- a EU citizen family member with one of the previous reason

To be self-employed, the easy way is getting a "Partita Iva" from the Revenue (Agenzia delle Entrate). It's free to get, but then you will need to keep a number of documents and compile several periodical declaration. I strongly suggest you to speak with an accountant (commercialista), because failing to comply with the bureaucracy can cost you a lot of money.
Keep in mind that, depending of the fiscal regime you will use (talk to your commercialista), you may need to pay some taxes and mandatory pension contribution even if you are earning nothing at all.

You could try to come in Italy and start your business in the first 3 months, so you can get the permission to stay more. After 5 years, you will the right of permanent residency.

The hard part will be finding clients for your business, I wish you the best but in Italy there still a lot of discrimination due to sex, age, religion, race, etc ant the economical situation is still declining.